# numerical scheme's conservation over time

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

Consider a conservative scheme
$$
u_{j}^{n+1}=u_{j}^{n}-\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}\left[g\left(u_{j+\frac{1}{2}}^{L}, u_{j+\frac{1}{2}}^{R}\right)-g\left(u_{j-\frac{1}{2}}^{L}, u_{j-\frac{1}{2}}^{R}\right)\right]
$$
for solving the initial value problem
$$
u_{t}+f(u)_{x}=0
$$
where $g(,)$ is a numerical flux function. How can we show that the total $u(x, t)$ of the numerical solution is conserved over time.

Comment: You want to show that $\sum_j u_j^{n+1} = \sum_j u_j^{n}$ so sum the equation over $j=1,2,\ldots,n$ and see what you get. Most terms will cancel (telescoping). For the remaining terms: boundary conditions.